# File Manager - Other Locations - SMB - Forget previous credentials

Tags: networking, login, samba

I'm new to Linux, and I'm using Ubuntu 18.10. I added a smb folder using the file manager other locations, and logged in to my network folder with my username and password. I now need to log back into the same network folder as a different user, but as I selected dont forget my credentials last time I am no longer presented with the option to login as a user and can't see anyway to tell file manager to forget the previously entered credentials. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of the following command in Terminal: `ls ~/.config/nautilus`?

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late reply. i get :
desktop-metadata  search-metadata